# API Request to RAPID API gives StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

Tags: c#

I am trying to connect to a Rapid API, but get StatusCode {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'
I am how ever able to get a reply from Postman during testing.
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?
This is what I have:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://email-checker.p.rapidapi.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "MyKey");
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?domain=google.com");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're calling `GET https://email-checker.p.rapidapi.com/google.com`, is that on purpose or just a dummy value?

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake in my posting.
I have corrected it now.
This is the request that works from Postman: https://mailcheck.p.rapidapi.com?domain=google.com

Comment: That links to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys which says you need a header called `"X-RapidAPI-Key"`, I don't see that header added in your code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I didn't look in the API docs of that site. But if OP was able to do a sucessfull Postman request, I assumed, at least the type of authentication was correct ...

Comment: @derpirscher Don't assume, if there's no example of the Postman request then we don't know how it was done

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you so much.
Adding the headers did the trick!